# Politica de privacidade e bloqueio de cookies no navegador

Tags: php, internet-explorer, navegador-de-internet, cookies

Bom dia, pus um sistema de lembrar usuário no meu programa em php, utilizei cookies para isso, como achei no Google uma explicação sobre eles, mas me deparei com o seguinte: o IE e alguns navegadores se não todos hoje, bloqueiam cookies que não tenham uma politica de privacidade.
Busquei sobre isso e não achei nada alem de como habilitar cookies em seu navegador.

O que gostaria de saber e se tem como eu fazer com que o navegador aceite os cookies sem precisar de que o usuário vá em configurações para habilitar o tal cookie ou se tem uma outra forma de fazer com que a informação do usuário fique salva no navegador para ele voltar depois e não ter que digitar a senha toda vez, ou se existe uma outra forma de fazer o lembrar sem utilizar cookie.

grato desde já.

Comment: Salvar cookie é opcional, leve em conta fatores de segurança que implicam essa escolha. Se você pudesse manipular a configuração dos cookies que o usuário fez, seria uma falha terrível do navegador.

Comment: mas como eu faria para ao voltar para o navegador, apos fecha-lo, eu continuar conectado no sistema? visto que nem todo navegador aceita localstorage ainda, menos ainda o ie (acho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **COOKIE** é um mecanismo interessante mas como mencionado pode ser bloqueado pelo navegador. Esta é uma característica e nada pode fazer para mudar.

Para poder manter dados de navegação as `Sessões` é a alternativa. Para a sua melhor compreensão diria:

**COOKIE** pode ser ajustado para um longo tempo de vida, o que significa que os dados armazenados em um **cookie** podem ser armazenados durante meses ou mesmo anos. **Cookies**, *são armazenados no cliente*, trabalham sem problemas e são um mecanismo importante quando você trabalha especialmente com um *cluster* de servidores Web.

**IMPORTANTE:** não é suposto conter informação vital e é boa prática que a informação neles contida seja assinada digitalmente.

**As sessões** são armazenadas no lado do servidor, o que significa que os clientes não têm acesso à informação que é guardada neles - isto é particularmente importante se você armazenar *carrinhos de compras* ou outras informações que não quer que os seus visitantes editem manualmente como pode acontecer nos *COOKIES*. **Os dados da sessão**, sendo armazenados no lado do servidor, não precisam de ser transmitidos em cada acesso de cada página; precisa apenas de um ID por cada acesso e os dados são carregados a partir do *"arquivo local"*.

Mencionei um arquivo local e se leu referi sempre a expressão "armazenados no lado do servidor", mas foi intencional, isto porque o mecanismo do PHP por defeito entrega a capacidade de gravação de dados de sessão em ficheiros no servidor. No entanto é importante referir que o conceito contempla a possibilidade de se implementar o mecanismo próprio de gestão de sessões, como por exemplo em base de dados. Útil em ambiente de *cluster* de servidores Web.

**NOTA:** Finalmente, as sessões podem ser de qualquer tamanho que você quiser, porque eles são mantidos em seu servidor, enquanto muitos navegadores têm um limite para os cookies, além de os poderem bloquear.

Comment: entendo, mas, no lugar de cookie, como eu faria para armazenar uma informação vitalicia dentro do navegador do cliente? já que localstorage não se aplica a todo navegador, o que me fez ter que criar uma gambiarra, simplesmente eu seto o cookie, verifico se o cookie está setado, se não, seto um localstorage, verifico se o local storage esta setado, se não, utilizo o js.cookie para setar um cookie com js, verifico se o cookie esta setado, se nao, o que eu posso fazer? existe outra forma ou a forma de fazer isso? inserir uma informação que nunca apaga no navegador do cliente?

Comment: o problema de utilizar o js.cookie é que terá mais um download para fazer no celular do cliente, ou seja, mais peso para o site, quero evitar downloads desnecessários para o cliente, principalmente para fazer uma coisinha apenas, mesmo que eu chame ele apenas quando a variável PHP é acionada.

Comment: @flourigh como eu disse o cookie tem limitações nada pode fazer.. dei uma alternativa...que pelo que indica e tendo em conta que não quer sobrecarregar o cliente me parece a melhor opção.

Comment: no caso você diz, utilizar session? mas isso ira apagar sempre que fechar o navegador, impondo ao cliente, digitar as informações novamente? não podendo salvar para sempre a informação, estou correto em entender assim?

Comment: @flourigh meu caro... ainda nem votou na minha resposta! respondendo à sua pergunta... o mundo não é perfeito e a tecnologia tem também as suas limitações. não sei o seu nivel de conhecimento mas investigue um pouco sobre JWT , Sessions e cookies e certamente encontrará uma resposta para o seu problema. O que descreve é algo que está implícito no funcionamento deste tipo de mecanismo.  Se pretender uma ajuda mais séria... posso ajudar!

Comment: grato, estou aprendendo, e me deparei com o não uso de cookies pelos navegadores modernos